# Issues with AES Encryption using SynCrypto

Tags: delphi, encryption, cryptography, aes

Am trying to encrypt a file using [SynCrypto.pas](https://github.com/synopse/SynPDF/blob/master/SynCrypto.pas) with AES 256, but it fails if I try to encrypt a file whose size is not a multiple of 16 bytes. The decrypted data contains junk.

Example:

- Original string in txt file

  > we are testing the file
- Encrypted String

  > [ù[„|wáî}f  *!4ìÙw¬•ü¨s
- Decrypted String

  > we are testing tÝp?J

Here is my Encryption Code

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  A: TAES;
  Key: TSHA256Digest;
  s, B: TAESBlock;
  ks: integer;
  st: RawByteString;
  InStream, OutStream: TFileStream;
  SuperNo, TheSize, StreamSize: Int64;

begin
  InStream := TFileStream.Create('test.txt', fmOpenRead);
  OutStream := TFileStream.Create('out.txt', fmCreate);

  InStream.Position := 0;
  OutStream.Position := 0;
  st := '1234essai';
  ks := 256;
  SHA256Weak(st, Key);
  A.EncryptInit(Key, ks);
  StreamSize := InStream.Size;
  while InStream.Position < StreamSize do
  begin
    TheSize := StreamSize - InStream.Position;
    if TheSize < 16 then
    begin
      SuperNo := StreamSize - InStream.Position;

    end
    else
    begin
      SuperNo := 16;
    end;
    InStream.ReadBuffer(s, SuperNo);

    A.Encrypt(s, B);
    OutStream.WriteBuffer(B, SuperNo);
  end;
  A.Done;
  ShowMessage('Finish');
  InStream.Free;
  OutStream.Free;
end;
```

Here is my Decryption Code

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  A: TAES;
  Key: TSHA256Digest;
  s, B: TAESBlock;
  ks: integer;
  st: RawByteString;
  InStream, OutStream: TFileStream;
  SuperNo, TheSize, StreamSize: Int64;

begin
  InStream := TFileStream.Create('out.txt', fmOpenRead);
  OutStream := TFileStream.Create('in.txt', fmCreate);

  InStream.Position := 0;
  OutStream.Position := 0;
  st := '1234essai';
  ks := 256;
  SHA256Weak(st, Key);
  A.DecryptInit(Key, ks);
  StreamSize := InStream.Size;
  while InStream.Position < StreamSize do
  begin
    TheSize := StreamSize - InStream.Position;
    if TheSize < 16 then
    begin
      SuperNo := StreamSize - InStream.Position;

    end
    else
    begin
      SuperNo := 16;
    end;
    InStream.ReadBuffer(s, SuperNo);

    A.Decrypt(s, B);

    OutStream.WriteBuffer(B, SuperNo);
  end;
  A.Done;
  ShowMessage('Finish');
  InStream.Free;
  OutStream.Free;
end;
```

Using Delphi XE7.

Comment: Most encryption algorithms work with fixed size data blocks. This means that your input data size needs to be the multiple of data block size. So you should extend last block of your file to be of correct size. Naturally you will remove this extended data on decompression so you also need to store this information in your encrypted file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AES is a *block cipher* algorithm. It means that it works by blocks that are 16 bytes in size for AES. So you need to use *padding* if your data does not fit in 16 bytes blocks (which is the case for your text).

Instead of trying to re-invent the wheel, and introduce mistakes, you would rather rely on existing padding algorithm. And you should add a [block chaining mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation). Currently the default algorithm you are using is ECB, which is known to be weak, since it does not use a chaining mode nor an Initialization Vector (IV).

The `SynCrypto` unit contains a safe block chaining mode like CFB and PKCS7 padding, so you could write:

```
var inp,out: RawByteString;
begin
  // encryption:
  inp := StringFromFile('in.txt');
  out := TAESCFB.SimpleEncrypt(inp,'privatekey',true,true);
  FileFromString(out,'out.txt');
  // or in a single line:
  FileFromString(TAESCFB.SimpleEncrypt(StringFromFile('in.txt'),'privatekey',true,true),'out.txt');
  // decryption
  inp := StringFromFile('out.txt');
  out := TAESCFB.SimpleEncrypt(inp,'privatekey',false,true);
  FileFromString(out,'in.txt');
end;
```

The above code is safe and fast, will generate the binary key using SHA-256 over the supplied `'privatekey'`, and will use AES-NI hardware instructions if you CPU supports it. You can use another chaining mode, just by changing the `TAESCFB` class name to another type available.

Comment: thanks for your explanation.
one more thing, could you show an example of encrypting a TBytes or buffer ?

Comment: Made some changes (I started off just writing cipher correctly). The general gist was alright, but CFB doesn't require padding (and your code doesn't perform padding) so I removed that bit if you don't mind.

Comment: @ Arnaud Bouchez, finally figured it out. Thanks.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes TAESAbstract.SimpleEncrypt **does** perform PKCS7 padding. Just check the method code. And such padding, even if not mandatory with CFB, is still used in this particular implementation, since we apply the CFB using 16 bytes chunks (via a single XMM register), directly in the input/output memory buffers, for speed.

Comment: @Xor-el There is an overloaded TAESAbstract.EncryptPKCS7() method which accepts `TBytes`.

Comment: Note that everybody calls these chunks *blocks*. I think it is not very smart to deviate from the standard for speed purposes. I also wonder how the implementation is faster that way; you can just only XOR those bytes of the key stream required for the plaintext - where's the speedup? I just viewed the code, it is (slightly) documented that you do this. Note that calling a method `pkcs7Encrypt` is pretty dangerous as well. PKCS#7 describes the Cryptographic Message Syntax, not just PKCS#7 padding.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes What do you call a 'standard'? Padding is not mandatory for CFB or OFB, so not commonly used, but still possible, if both ends agree on that. The point of the SimpleEncrypt() method is to propose a simple way of having a safe encryption - with padding. PKCS#7 is indeed more than padding, but I guess that the documentation of EncryptPKCS7/DecryptPKCS7 states "encrypt/decrypt a memory buffer using a PKCS7 padding pattern". It is always stated as "PKCS7 padding pattern", not "PKCS7 Message" - isn't it clear enough? I've added that it doesn't implement Cryptographic Message Syntax.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez The addition of padding means that many API's won't be compatible as few of them provide padding functionality separately. It also means that you cannot decrypt any standard ciphertext. If you just want to use the library by itself then this is of course OK. Yeah, documentation can make up for the name, although I like my methods to be self-descriptive (up to reasonable limits of course). I would not go as far as to rename your API for it, just something to keep in mind for the next one :P